# how to install ubuntu server 12.04 through netboot using pxe

Tags: 12.04, dhcp, pxe, syslinux, tftp

I have Ubuntu Server 12.04 installed as server. Also tftp server, dhcp3-server, syslinux and apache were installed on it. There are lots of clients which I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 on them through local network.

I used nfs to install 12.04-server with these [DisklessUbuntuHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) and [PXE install Ubuntu Server using NFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638012/pxe-install-ubuntu-server-using-nfs) and many others. Installer loads but it is not using Local Network NFS, it is asking for Network Mirror (this works for ubuntu 14.04-desktop and install successfully). Client supports PXE boot and gets IP from dhcp3-server, tftp transfer kernel (linux) and initrd.gz completely, everything is fine till asking for mirrors.

I also used memdisk which 12.04-server.iso load correctly (client has 2Gb ram, doesn't matter if tftp is slow yet) and its grub appear. I did like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334529/pxe-booting-ubuntu-into-a-ramdisk?rq=1) and many others same as [Syslinux wiki](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php) which describe Memdisk. When I try to install, first questions are fine, but asking for cdrom and says cannot mount it.

Furthermore, I setup local mirror list and http server (e.g. http://10.9.1.101/ubuntu/). mount `12.04-server.iso` with -o loop in `/var/www/ubuntu/` (or also one time tried to copy them and of course I copied .disk directory). I answer my local mirror list which works till installing base system and I got this message:

```
Debootstrap warning
Warning:
http://10.9.1.101/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binayr-amd64/Packages was corrupt
```

When I use an Internet mirror list, it install successfully. I checked apache logs installation looks for precise-updates instead.

I checked md5sum the ISO file from ubuntu.com site and were the same.
I searched a lot but they didn't have a working answer.

My question is how to install `ubuntu-12.04-server.iso` on many clients through local network?